# How to remove a specific string from a variable

Tags: c++

I am programming a simple IDE for python for my own personal use, and on the writeFile function i have the option to input the command endl to start a new line and it works fine; however when i look at the file it produces it prints endl right before the new line.  so is there any way i can remove the "endl" from the variable and keep it from being written into the file.

```
    void writeFile()
    {
         ofstream fos("data.py");
         string data;
         bool done = false;
         string temp;
         cout << "Enter Some Data. Enter s to stop." << endl;
         while(!done)
         {
             cin >> data;
             if(data == "s")
             {
                 done = true;
             }
             else if(data == "endl")
             {
                   fos << data + "\n";
             }
             else if(data != "s" && data != "endl")
             {
                   fos << data + " ";
             }
         }
         fos.close();
}
```

Comment: It's hard to read when your question is in a big block. Reformat it, please. But in any case, are you saying you can see `endl` in the file but you are not supposed to? I guess `fos` is output to write, right? Then in your code, I see `fos << data + "\n";` If `data` contains `endl`, then it goes out to `fos.. right? If I am wrong, well, please rewrite your question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason `endl` is getting printed inside the file is because your are providing the `data` variable to the streaming object `fos` after checking for `endl or new line`. You can try this:

```
void writeFile()
{
 ofstream fos("data.py");
 string data;
 bool done = false;
 string temp;
 cout << "Enter Some Data. Enter s to stop." << endl;
 while(!done)
 {
     cin >> data;
     if(data == "s")
     {
         done = true;
     }
     else if(data == "endl")
     {
           fos <<"\n";
     }
     else if(data != "s" && data != "endl")
     {
           fos << data + " ";
     }
 }
 fos.close();
}
```

Comment: +1: if you stare long enough, you'll see a tree in that forest. Nice eye.

Comment: @aceassasin if you find some answer helpful, accept it.